# How to pass variables and FormData with Jquery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to update data of input field with ajax. Being new to Ajax, I've tried this so far. I am passing two variables(i.e, Name and Col to identify the name and id of the input field). So now I am stuck with this. I want to update the value of the input field with name="email_id" and Column name in mysql table "Email". So I passed the two variable so that php can identify the input name. But how do I pass the new data in the field? I have done it in another form with FormData but I need help in this case. And I apologise if I am not being specific, its my first query on stackoverflow.

HTML:

```
<input type="email" onblur="validate()" value="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>" id="email_id" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Invalid Email" data-placement="top" data-content="Email must be in the format xyz@abc.com/net/info/org/in" name="email_id" placeholder="E-mail ID eg. max@mymail.com" class="form-control col-sm">
```

Jquery:

```
$('input').on("change",function(){
    console.log("Clicked");
    var Name=$(this).attr('name');
    var Col=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log(Name);
    $.ajax({
        url:"update.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{"Col":Col,"Name":Name},
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: here both name and id are same wright, how can you distinguish  them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.getElementByID().value to grab the value of the input field:

```
$('input').on("change",function(){
            console.log("Clicked");
            var Val=document.getElementById('email_id').value;
            var Name=$(this).attr('name');
            var Col=$(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url:"update.php",
                method:"post",
                data:{"Col":Col,"Name":Name, "Email":Val},
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: No my friend, I want to pass the new value written inside the input field along with those two variables to the php file so that I can update the value of that field in my database.

Comment: Hi Punya, I've edited the answer to pass the input value with `document.getElementId('').value`. Try that out.

Comment: Well I figured it out and its the same as what you answered! But Thanks anyways :-)